# Cassandra alter column type: which types are compatible?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3

There's some patchy information on the interwebs about some examples when column type can't be changed. For example, on the [DataStax site](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/alter_table_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_xqq_hpc_xj__changing-the-type-of-a-column) there's a mention:

- Changing the type of a clustering column.
- Changing columns on which
  an index is defined.

Or, for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21539917/371804) is mentioned that you can't convert `uuid` to `timeuuid`. And from my personal experience, I can't change `text` to `timestamp` (we store dates in ISO8601 format as text, an unfortunate decision early in the project timeline).

However, I can't find a full description of which types can be converted to which, or at least which types *can't* be converted to which. Does anyone know?

Comment: I found this [link from DataStax](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cql_data_types_c.html#cql_data_types_c__cql_data_type_compatibility) for version 3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Great question!  I have to admit that I was a bit surprised at the lack of thorough documentation on this one, as well.  Your question inspired me to do a little investigation and [blog about it](http://www.aaronstechcenter.com/cassandra-compatible-types.php) as well.

Essentially, here is a comprehensive list of Cassandra compatible CQL types *(using Cassandra 2.2.0)*:

- **ascii** -> blob, text, varchar
- **bigint** -> blob, timestamp, varint
- **int** -> blob, varint
- **text** -> blob, varchar
- **timestamp** -> bigint, blob, varint
- **timeuuid** -> blob, UUID
- **varchar** -> blob, text

Notes:

- blob is in there a lot, because *anything* can be converted to a blob.
- cqlsh allows you to convert a varint to the new date type, but this is a bug ([CASSANDRA-10027](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10027)).  Don't actually try that.

Comment: I am surprised to know that one can't change any type to collection of that type.
For e.q changing text to List<text>.

Comment: bigint -> timestamp causes an error "Altering of types is not allowed" in CQLSH 5 and Cassandra 3.11

Answer (score 3):

The 2020 answer:

This functionality seems to have been completely removed. [The version 6.8 documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.8/cql/cql/cql_reference/cql_commands/cqlAlterTable.html)
states:

> Cannot change the data type of a column.

Comment: It's removed started with Cassandra 3.0 (DSE 5.0)