# Cassandra cqlengine not reflecting model schema changes - migration

Tags: python, cassandra

I followed the cassandra cqlengine tutorial.

```
import uuid
from cassandra.cqlengine import columns
from cassandra.cqlengine import connection
from datetime import datetime
from cassandra.cqlengine.management import sync_table
from cassandra.cqlengine.models import Model

class ExampleModel(Model):
    example_id      = columns.UUID(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    example_type    = columns.Integer(index=True)
    created_at      = columns.DateTime()
    description     = columns.Text(required=False)

connection.setup(['127.0.0.1'], "cqlengine", protocol_version=3)
sync_table(ExampleModel)
```

However when i change a field in the model, like if i change the field description from Text type to Integer type, and then do a sync_table, i dont see the change being reflected in the tables schema in cassandra. How can this be solved ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two things wrong here:

1. Conceptually, you are attempting a schema migration. The apache Cassandra driver for python does not really support schema migration officially yet. A quick look at [this ticket](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/PYTHON-383) will explain to you what I mean. (Note: you could add new column to your table and `sync_table` will work and your new schema will be reflected but that is not strictly speaking an `ALTER` operation.)
2. Cassandra data type conversions in a data model must follow the CQL type compatibility, which is defined [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/cql_data_types_c.html#concept_ds_wbk_zdt_xj__cql_data_type_compatibility). Your attempt to convert from `Integer` to `Float` is not compatible.

The only solution so far to update schema with imcompatible types is outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34940989/how-to-convert-int-column-to-float-double-column-in-cassandra-database-table). I opened a separate discussion on the same [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41569551/incompatible-schema-migration-cassandra).